# ReactiveUI subscribe to property change in ReactiveList

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

There is any way of subscribing to any field changed in `ReactiveList`?

Lets say I have class:

```
public class A
{
        public SomeOtherClass Prop1 { get; set; }
        public SomeOtherClass Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ReactiveList<A> elements;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        elements = new ReactiveList<A>();
    }
}
```

This list is binded to `DataGrid`. What I want to do is something like `WhenAnyValue` but when `Prop1` or `Prop2` are changed in any A in `elements`.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `ChangeTrackingEnabled` property of the `ReactiveList<T>` to true and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setters of the `Prop1` and `Prop2` properties you can subscribe to `ItemChanged` of the `ReactiveList<T>`:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    elements = new ReactiveList<A>() { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
    elements.ItemChanged.Subscribe(args =>
    {
        A a = args.Sender;
        string changedProperty = args.PropertyName;
    });
}
```

Note that the `A` class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.